# HTML5 Video Cross-Browser Preloading

Tags: javascript, performance, cross-browser, html5-video, preloading

On my website I have a model with 12 videos that are layered on each other and play on a button click.

I have been looking for a solution to preload all videos and play immediately on click with no pauses/lag.

I found this plugin https://github.com/synthecypher/full-preload
It works great for all browser except IE9 and safari iOS.

Looks like the Blob is not supported in IE9, but I'm not sure what is happening on Safari IOS.

The developer tools show me this error after the video is fully loaded and trying to play:

```
[Error] Unhandled Promise Rejection: NotSupportedError: The operation is not supported.
    (anonymous function)
    rejectPromise
```

For the example of the plugin in action you can check http://courts-dev.com/full-preload/

Did anyone experience this before? I really need to have this supported on tablets, I don't worry so much about IE9.

Comment: Mobile devices won't preload multiple videos as a bandwidth savings measure

Comment: Hi j08691, thanks for reply. Are you sure there is no workaround? Did you take a look at the plugin example? It's using xhr to get the video, and it does load the whole video for me on iOS tablet, but can't play it for some reason..